# Cypher Query to Filter SCENARIO Nodes Based on GAP Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with a Neo4j database with a data model with GAP and SCENARIO nodes. Each GAP node has a "next" property that lists the keys of connected SCENARIO nodes. The SCENARIO nodes have a "parents" property indicating how many parent nodes they have. I want to filter SCENARIO nodes based on a list of selected GAP nodes and the number of parents.

Here is how GAP nodes are supposed to SCENARIO nodes:

- gap1 key:g1
- gap2 key:g2
- gap3 key:g3

---

- scenario1 key:  s1
- scenario2 key:  s2
- scenario3 key: s3

---

- parents of scenario 1 are: gap1, gap2
- parents of scenario 2 are: gap1, gap2, gap3
- parents of scenario 3 are: gap2

Here is my GAP and SCENARIO nodes model:

```
 (gap1:GAP {name:  'g1',
            key:   'g1',
            desc:  '',
            next:  's1,s2'
  }),
//GAP2
  (gap2:GAP {name:  'g2',
             key:   'g2',
             desc:  '',
             next:  's1,s2,s3'
  }),
//GAP3
  (gap3:GAP {name:  'g3',
             key:   'g3',
             desc:  'g3',
             next:  's2'
  }),

//SCENARIO
  (scenario1:SCENARIO {name:    's1',
                       key:     's1',
                       DESC:    '',
                       parents: 2
                       }),
  (scenario2:SCENARIO {name:    's2',
                       key:     's2',
                       DESC:    '',
                       parents: 3
                       }),
  (scenario3:SCENARIO {name:    's3',
                       key:     's3',
                       DESC:    '',
                       parents: 1}),
```

If a gap is provided as input in the query and it is a parent of a scenario, but the number of parents of that scenario is more than 1 in the parent node, it should exclude the scenario from the result. If two gaps are provided, and both are parents of a single scenario, other scenario nodes are included. Still, the parent condition only meets for that single node; it should only return that single node.

I have tried too many combinations but always fail somewhere.
This query somehow worked, but it failed for the following conditions:

1. When g1,g2 are provided, it should return s1 only. it returns all three scenario
2. if g1 is provided, it should return empty, but it returns s1,s2
3. if g2 is provided, it should return only s3 but it returns all s1,s2,s3

I have been stuck on this for around three days but have been unable to figure out a solution. Please note that, per the scenario, a direct link from GAP to SCENARIO will not solve the problem.

```
MATCH (gap:GAP)
WHERE gap.name IN ['g1', 'g2', 'g3']

WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT gap) AS selectedGaps

WHERE size(selectedGaps) > 0  

MATCH (scenario:SCENARIO)
WHERE ANY(gap IN selectedGaps WHERE scenario.key IN split(gap.next, ','))
RETURN scenario.name AS ScenarioName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inconsistencies in your sample data.

- `scenario2` says it has 3 parents, but there are only 2 `GAP` nodes containing the `s2` key.
- `scenario3` says it has 1 parent, but there are actually 2 `GAP` nodes containing the `s3` key.

Here is a query that should work, assuming you fix your data to be consistent:

```
MATCH (gap:GAP)
WHERE gap.name IN $gaps
UNWIND SPLIT(gap.next, ',') AS sKey
WITH sKey, COUNT(*) AS cnt
WITH COLLECT({sKey: sKey, cnt: cnt}) AS data
MATCH (s:SCENARIO)
WHERE ANY(d IN data WHERE d.sKey = s.key AND d.cnt = s.parents)
RETURN s.name AS ScenarioName;
```

The query assumes that the list of `GAP` names is provided as a `$gaps` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).

##### Suggested new model

You should strongly consider changing your data model, however. You are not using any relationships, which is the main strength of a graph database. `GAP` and `SCENARIO` nodes should not store relationship information as properties, but should be linked by actual relationships. I would also recommend conforming to the [recommended neo4j naming convention](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/#_recommendations), where labels are camel-cased.

For example, this could conceptually be your new data model (without the `next` and `parents` properties):

```
(g:Gap {name, key, desc})-[:HAS_SCENARIO]->(s:Scenario {name, key, desc})
```

With this new model, the query for your use case would simply be:

```
MATCH (g:Gap)-[:HAS_SCENARIO]->(s:Scenario)
WHERE g.name IN $gaps
WITH s, COUNT(g) AS cnt
WHERE COUNT{ ()-[:HAS_SCENARIO]->(s) } = cnt
RETURN s.name AS scenarioName;
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake in the model. I have corrected it and the query works exactly as needed. Regarding the suggested data model, what I am trying to do is to generate a kind of dynamic graph that creates edges on the go if a certain condition like this matches for SCENARIO nodes. the scenario nodes will be linked to multiple GAP nodes using next. Is not this approach correct?

Comment: This use case is from a larger graph.

Comment: Unless otherwise required, it is best practice to create the desired data model when ingesting data, rather than fixing up the data model later (otherwise your database has multiple confusing and conflicting data models, and is vulnerable to race conditions). And it is definitely best practice to use relationships instead of properties that try to mimic relationships -- you are giving up the main advantage of native graph DBs.